# Best practise database prefixes in tables?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database which has users and a todo list for these user (and a lot more tables but that's irrelevant).

A user can have multiple todo items but an item can only be linked to one user.

**I was wondering how to create a table for the todo items?**
- Should I just call it something like: todo-items
- As it is for users should I call it: users_todoitems
- Should I give it a prefix, like: u_todoitems?

I tried searching for best practices regarding these type of problems, but couldn't find a good answer.

Comment: Just call it `todos`, or change the terminology to `tasks`.

Comment: @mul14 Even if only users use this table?

Comment: How many type of users do you have?

Comment: The table is used by all users. I am unsure about what you mean with 'type of users'.

Comment: What I meant was—maybe you have `teachers`, `soldiers`, etc. Each user type have their own todos. For example `teacher_todos`, `soldier_todos`. If only 1 type of users, it's fine name it as `todos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having different user tables is upto how normalized you want your db design to be.
If you think deep, todos are actually a list which can have more than one task. So, it's more logical to connect todo list to user rather than connecting tasks. So, one user can have more than one todo list and each todo list can have more than one task.

I would advise to go with the following table design:

`users` table

- user_id (primary key)
- other_fields

`user_todo_lists` table

- todo_list_id (primary key)
- user_id_fk (foreign key)

`todo_list_tasks` table

- task_id (primary key)
- todo_list_id_fk (foreign key)
- task_name
- other_task_fields

This design works well even for your worst query of an `user` not having even one todo task. In such case your search is limited to `user_todo_lists` table and not the massive `todo_list_tasks` table.

Comment: In my case a user does not have more than one todo list. So I don't think I need to 'seperate' the list from the items. However, is it a bad practice having a list of todoitems linked directly to a user? Would it be better to create a list and the items to that list? Because it sounds like it would be faster database wise.

Comment: If you anticipate many users to **not** have any task associated to them, then go ahead and create the list table.It will **save** your from searching your entire table to return no record exists for user who haven't created a task.

Comment: Forgot to mark as answer, thanks for the explanation